# Heap Sort: how to sort?

Tags: python, sorting, computer-science, heapsort

I'm trying to implement Heap Sort in Python, but I can't seem to get it right. I've tried to implement this [pseudo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), but my code does not sort! It just sifts to ridiculous effect. I'm inclined to think that the problem is in this line:

> swap the root(maximum value) of the heap with the last element of the heap

How do I get the maximum value?

That is what I have:

```
def my_heap_sort(sqc):                    
    def heapify(count):                
        start = (count-2)/2            
        while start >= 0:              
            sift_down(start, count-1)  
            start -= 1                 

    def swap(i, j):                    
        sqc[i], sqc[j] = sqc[j], sqc[i]

    def sift_down(start, end):         
        root = start                   

        while (root * 2 + 1) <= end:   
            child = root * 2 + 1       
            temp = root                
            if sqc[temp] < sqc[child]: 
                temp = child+1         
            if temp != root:           
                swap(root, temp)       
                root = temp            
            else:                      
                return                 

    count = len(sqc)                   
    heapify(count)                     

    end = count-1                      

    while end > 0:                     
        swap(end, 0)                   
        end -= 1                       
        sift_down(0, end)
```

And I found an example with almost the same problem:

```
def heap_sort_example(a):                                 
    def heapify(a):                                       
        start = (len(a) - 2) / 2                          
        start -= 1                                        

    def sift_down(a, start, end):                         
        root = start                                      
        while root * 2 + 1 <= end:                        
            child = root * 2 + 1                          
            if child + 1 <= end and a[child] < a[child+1]:
                child += 1                                
            if child <= end and a[root] < a[child]:       
                a[root], a[child] = a[child], a[root]     
                root = child                              
            else:                                         
                return                                    

    heapify(a)                                            
    end = len(a) - 1                                      
    while end > 0:                                        
        a[end], a[0] = a[0], a[end]                       
        sift_down(a, 0, end-1)                            
        end -= 1
```

The results are different, but both are ridiculous:

```
>>> my_heap_sort(sqc)
[2, 7, 1, -2, 56, 5, 3]

>>> heap_sort_example(sqc)
[-2, 1, 7, 2, 56, 5, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it and almost figured how it works:

```
def heapsort(sqc):                                 
    def down_heap(sqc, k, n):                            
        parent = sqc[k]                                  

        while 2*k+1 < n:                                 
            child = 2*k+1                                
            if child+1 < n and sqc[child] < sqc[child+1]:
                child += 1                               
            if parent >= sqc[child]:                     
                break                                    
            sqc[k] = sqc[child]                          
            k = child                                    
        sqc[k] = parent                                  

    size = len(sqc)                                      

    for i in range(size/2-1, -1, -1):                    
        down_heap(sqc, i, size)                          

    for i in range(size-1, 0, -1):                       
        sqc[0], sqc[i] = sqc[i], sqc[0]                  
        down_heap(sqc, 0, i)
```

## edit:

This implementation is written based on my own understanding of the algorithm. It is longer, but to me this algorithm is much clearer in this implementation. Long naming is help when you need to understand the algorithm, so I left intact all the long names.

```
def heapsort(sequence):                                                      
    sequence_length = len(sequence)                                          

    def swap_if_greater(parent_index, child_index):                          
        if sequence[parent_index] < sequence[child_index]:                   
            sequence[parent_index], sequence[child_index] =\                 
                    sequence[child_index], sequence[parent_index]            

    def sift(parent_index, unsorted_length):                                 
        index_of_greater = lambda a, b: a if sequence[a] > sequence[b] else b
        while parent_index*2+2 < unsorted_length:                            
            left_child_index = parent_index*2+1                              
            right_child_index = parent_index*2+2                             

            greater_child_index = index_of_greater(left_child_index,         
                    right_child_index)                                       

            swap_if_greater(parent_index, greater_child_index)               

            parent_index = greater_child_index                               

    def heapify():                                                           
        for i in range((sequence_length/2)-1, -1, -1):                       
            sift(i, sequence_length)                                         

    def sort():                                                              
        count = sequence_length                                              
        while count > 0:                                                     
            count -= 1                                                       
        swap_if_greater(count, 0)                                        
        sift(0, count)                                                   

    heapify()                                                                
    sort()
```

## edit:

And optimized version:

```
def opt_heapsort(s):                               
    sl = len(s)                                    

    def swap(pi, ci):                              
        if s[pi] < s[ci]:                          
            s[pi], s[ci] = s[ci], s[pi]            

    def sift(pi, unsorted):                        
        i_gt = lambda a, b: a if s[a] > s[b] else b
        while pi*2+2 < unsorted:                   
            gtci = i_gt(pi*2+1, pi*2+2)            
            swap(pi, gtci)                         
            pi = gtci                              
    # heapify                                      
    for i in range((sl/2)-1, -1, -1):              
        sift(i, sl)                                
    # sort                                         
    for i in range(sl-1, 0, -1):                   
        swap(i, 0)                                 
        sift(0, i)
```

Answer (score 17):

**How do I get the maximum value?** You don't need to "get" it. The root is exactly the maximum, that's a defined property of a heap.

If you feel tough to understand heap sort, [this chapter](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&pg=PA127&dq=introduction%20to%20algorithm%20heap%20sort&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=HnnTULG2Ga6QiAfhyoEQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20algorithm%20heap%20sort&f=false) will be extremely helpful.

---

I rewrote your code:

```
def swap(i, j):                    
    sqc[i], sqc[j] = sqc[j], sqc[i] 

def heapify(end,i):   
    l=2 * i + 1  
    r=2 * (i + 1)   
    max=i   
    if l < end and sqc[i] < sqc[l]:   
        max = l   
    if r < end and sqc[max] < sqc[r]:   
        max = r   
    if max != i:   
        swap(i, max)   
        heapify(end, max)   

def heap_sort():     
    end = len(sqc)   
    start = end // 2 - 1 # use // instead of /
    for i in range(start, -1, -1):   
        heapify(end, i)   
    for i in range(end-1, 0, -1):   
        swap(i, 0)   
        heapify(i, 0)   

sqc = [2, 7, 1, -2, 56, 5, 3]
heap_sort()
print(sqc)
```

It gives:

```
[-2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 56]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have push and pop, or are using built-in heapq lib, try documented solution:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
def heapsort(iterable):
    h = []
    for value in iterable:
        heappush(h, value)
    return [heappop(h) for i in range(len(h))]

heapsort([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: anything in documentation is probably good practice (https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#basic-examples, same for python3). it is not stable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) though, which depends on the application. review the heap data structure (https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/06sp/handouts/lecture10.pdf) if you have time before the interview, and consider what language, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the different implementations of heapify, the "heart" of heap sort are not clear on the internetz. Here is my humble attempt to help the community by adding a simple but clear example of "heapify". I use vectors to avoid the extra confusion of array manipulation.

This method heapifies 1 cell of the array.
To heapify the whole array you need a loop, 
run it from middle of array, moving to beginning.
The returned vector MUST be the same one we send in the next iteration, 
otherwise it's a mess.
eg:

```
for (int i = myvector.size()/2; i >= 0; i--) { in = Heapify(in, i);}

vector_of_int Sort::Heapify(vector_of_int in_vector, int in_index)
{

int min_index = in_index; // Track index of smallest out of parent and two children.
int left_child_index = 0; 
int right_child_index = 0;
int vector_size = in_vector.size(); 

left_child_index = LeftChildIndex(in_index);// index of left child, at position 2*in_index
right_child_index = left_child_index + 1;// index of right child, at position 2*in_index + 1

// If left_child_index is not overflowing, suggest swap...
if ((left_child_index) < vector_size) 
{
    // If parent larger than left child, min_index remembers left child position
    if (in_vector[min_index] > in_vector[left_child_index]) 
    { min_index = left_child_index; }
}

// If right_child_index is is not overflowing, suggest swap...
if (right_child_index < vector_size) 
{
    // If parent larger than right child, min_index remembers right child position
    if (in_vector[min_index] > in_vector[right_child_index]) 
    { min_index = right_child_index; }
}

// Now min_index has the index of the smallest out of parent and it's two children.
// If the smallest is not the parent, swap parent and smallest.
if (min_index != in_index) 
{
    in_vector = swap(in_vector, in_index ,min_index);
    in_vector = Heapify(in_vector, min_index); // RECURSION IS HERE
}

return in_vector;
}
// End heapify
```

Answer (score 0):

selection sort is a relatively straight forward sorting algorithm:
traverse an array, extract the minimun of the first n elements , then extract min of the next n-1 elements ......
Now this would be O(n^2) algorithm.

Since you are always extracting a min you should think of using a minimum Heap. it extracts a min in O(log n) time. extracting the min n times leads to O(n*log n) time.

so for heap sort one just needs to build a heap (heapify O(n)) and the traverse the array and extract the min n times.

you can use the python [heap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) to build a heap or build your own.

```
def heapsort(l):
    hp = make_heap(l)
    for i in range(len(l)):
       yield hp.extract_min()
```

Comment: I see it useless to use the built-in library without knowledge of the algorithms. What if tomorrow I will have to write it in another language, which is not provided for such a possibility?

Comment: Where is the `make_heap` function?

Answer (score 0):

Heap sort example with example of how to initially build a heap

```
def findMin(heapArr,i,firstChildLoc,secondChildLoc):
        a = heapArr[i]
        b = heapArr[firstChildLoc]
        c = heapArr[secondChildLoc]
        return i if ((a < b) and (a < c)) else firstChildLoc if (b < c) else secondChildLoc


def prelocateUp(heapArr):
    l = len(heapArr)
    i = l-1
    while True:
        parentLoc = (i+1)/2 - 1 
        if parentLoc >= 0:
            if heapArr[parentLoc] > heapArr[i]:
                temp = heapArr[parentLoc]
                heapArr[parentLoc] = heapArr[i]
                heapArr[i] = temp  
        else :
            break
        i = parentLoc
    return heapArr

def prelocateDown(heapArr):

    l = len(heapArr)
    i = 0

    while True:
        firstChildLoc = 2*(i+1) - 1
        secondChildLoc = 2*(i+1)
        if (firstChildLoc > l-1):
            break

        elif (secondChildLoc > l-1):
            if heapArr[i] > heapArr[firstChildLoc]:
                temp = heapArr[i]
                heapArr[i] = heapArr[firstChildLoc]
                heapArr[firstChildLoc] = temp
            break

        else :
            minLoc = findMin(heapArr,i,firstChildLoc,secondChildLoc)
            if minLoc !=i:
                temp = heapArr[i]
                heapArr[i] = heapArr[minLoc]
                heapArr[minLoc] = temp
                i = minLoc
            else :
                break
    return heapArr



def heapify(heapArr,op):
    if op==1:
        heapArr = prelocateUp(heapArr)
    else :
        heapArr = prelocateDown(heapArr)
    return heapArr

def insertHeap(heapArr,num):
    heapArr.append(num)
    heapArr = heapify(heapArr,1)
    return heapArr

def getMin(heapArr):
    ele = heapArr[0]
    heapArr[0] = heapArr[-1]
    heapArr.pop(-1)
    heapArr = heapify(heapArr,2)
    return ele,heapArr

a=[5,4,8,2,6]
heapArr = []
for i in xrange(0,len(a)):
    heapArr = insertHeap(heapArr,a[i])

#No 
sortedArr = []
for i in xrange(0,len(a)):
    [ele,heapArr] = getMin(heapArr)
    sortedArr.append(ele)
print sortedArr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Heap Sorting on any given Number,Below Program will first convert it into binary heap tree and then its performing heap sorting**

class HeapSort():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hst_list=[None]
        self.final_list=[]

    def add_element(self,value):
        self.hst_list.append(value)

    def build_hst(self):
        for _ in range((len(self.hst_list)//2)):
            self.convert_into_hst()

    def get_left_child(self,idx):
        for m in range(len(self.hst_list)):
            if m==2*idx:
                return self.hst_list[2*idx]
        return 999

    def get_right_child(self,idx):
        for m in range(len(self.hst_list)):
            if m==2*idx+1:
                return self.hst_list[2*idx+1]
        return 999

    def convert_into_hst(self):
        i=1
        while i<=len(self.hst_list)//2: 
            left_child=self.get_left_child(i)
            right_child=self.get_right_child(i) 
            if self.hst_list[i]>=left_child:
                p_val=self.hst_list[i]
                self.hst_list[i]=left_child
                self.hst_list[2*i]=p_val
                #print(self.hst_list)
            elif self.hst_list[i]>=right_child:
                p_val=self.hst_list[i]
                self.hst_list[i]=right_child
                self.hst_list[2*i+1]=p_val
            i=i+1

    def print_hst(self):
        print(self.hst_list)
        print(self.final_list)

    def perform_sorting(self):
        for i in range(1,len(self.hst_list)):
            self.perform_heap_sorting()

    def perform_heap_sorting(self):
        self.final_list.append(self.hst_list[1])
        self.hst_list.pop(1)
        self.build_hst()
        print(self.final_list)

hst_obj=HeapSort()
hst_obj.add_element(10)
hst_obj.add_element(5)
hst_obj.add_element(5)
hst_obj.add_element(30)
hst_obj.add_element(15)
hst_obj.add_element(50)
hst_obj.add_element(25)
hst_obj.add_element(35)
hst_obj.add_element(1)
hst_obj.add_element(100)
hst_obj.build_hst()
hst_obj.perform_sorting()
```